# strpos returning false with $_GET Parameters

Tags: php

I've got the following snippet:

```
function RemoveSubdir(){
    // Get the requested path (including all slashes) and Convert to lowercase
    $Request_Path = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // Create an array, exploding at the forward slash
    $Request_Path = explode('/',$Request_Path);
    // return the last element being the file name requested
    $Arr_Elements = end($Request_Path);

    if (empty($Arr_Elements)){
        return prev($Request_Path);
    }
    return $Arr_Elements;
}

$Directory_Manipulation =  RemoveSubdir();


    echo $Directory_Manipulation;

var_dump(strpos('global.inc.php',$Directory_Manipulation));
```

I am currently pointing my browser to the correct file path (being 127.0.0.1/PayC/Global.inc.php) and the returns from the `RemoveSubdir()` returns the correct value of *global.inc.php* which is expected.. Everything is running fine at this moment in time, now the incorrect/unexpected validations come from the chunk of code:

```
strpos('global.inc.php',$Directory_Manipulation);
```

now, i'm expecting this to return anything other than `false`, which is fine when the URI is:

> 127.0.0.1/PayC/Global.inc.php

as shown: `int(0)`

But with the URI of

> 127.0.0.1/PayC/Global.inc.php?

I get a return of: `bool(false)`

I am aware that I could remove the trailing parameters after the .php extension, but I want to leave these intact.. I've tried debugging further but been resorted to `var_dumping` and posting my results here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to see if global.inc.php is inside of $Directory_Manipulation. In that case, you've got your parameters backwards! It should be

```
var_dump(strpos($Directory_Manipulation, 'global.inc.php'));
```

You can look at the php documentation for [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), too. :)

Comment: Ah. There we go. Even after looking at the documentation.. I was getting parameters the wrong way round. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a case sensitivity issue. Try this:

```
$Directory_Manipulation =  RemoveSubdir();
$DM_lower = strtolower($Directory_Manipulation);
```

And doing the `strpos()` using `$DM_lower` instead of `$Directory_Manipulation`.

Comment: Case sensitivity is not an issue as calling the function prior converts the parameters to lower case hence the line: `$Request_Path = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: If it was also a issue with the parameters case type. Then I would not be achieving a correct validation in the first URI Example

Comment: I'm directly modifying the $_SERVER array to convert to lowercase before manipulating further. I will give it a try, don't have high hopes

Comment: Same results & if it was a problem with upper/lower case I would have continued to use `stripos` which is the case insensitive check for a needle in the haystack